# Combinations with replacements

Tags: python, combinations

I know how to generate combinations of a set and that's a builtin in Python (what I use), anyway. But how to generate combinations with replacements?

Suppose I have a set with, say, two identical elements - for example, **AABCDE**.

Combinations of 3 items could be:

```
"AAB"
"ABC"
"CDE"
```

However, the program would count **ABC** twice - once when using the first A, and the second one using the second A.

What is a good way to generate such combinations without duplicates?

Thanks.

Comment: I am still confused as to what you want. Can you give the full output for the case "AABCDE"?

Comment: Yes.

Full output for AABCDE would be exactly like calling set on itertools.combinations(AABCDE).

If you have 2 pink chairs, 1 green chair and 1 blue chair, in how many ways can you combine them? Given that the pink chairs are for all purposes identical, and you can use the two pink chairs in the same combination.

Comment: "Suppose I have a set with, say, two identical elements" - **that is contradictory to the definition of a set**.

Answer (score 2):

convert it to `set`, that's the easiest way to get rid of duplicates.

Comment: No, I consider "AAC" a valid combination

Comment: so, how exactly is that contradicting my answer. build your list with duplicates, then apply set.

Comment: I thought you meant convert the original list to a set like the other guy suggested. It's still tricky. If I want combinations with replacements of a a list with many copies of the same item it's highly inefficient, plus you can't use it as an iterator

Comment: what do you mean by *can't use it as an iterator*?

Comment: I meant a generator - you have to make the entire list and then iterate over it. And what if I want to break the loop in the middle? That creates a huge waste.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> import itertools
>>> ["".join(x) for x in (itertools.combinations(set("AABCDE"),3))]
['ACB', 'ACE', 'ACD', 'ABE', 'ABD', 'AED', 'CBE', 'CBD', 'CED', 'BED']
>>>
```

From your other comments, I think I misunderstood what you are asking.

```
>>> import itertools
>>> set("".join(x) for x in (itertools.combinations("AABCDE",3)))
set(['AAE', 'AAD', 'ABC', 'ABD', 'ABE', 'AAC', 'AAB', 'BCD', 'BCE', 'ACD', 'CDE', 'ACE', 'ADE', 'BDE'])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def stepper_w_w(l,stop):#stepper_with_while
"""l is a list of any size usually you would input [1,1,1,1...],
stop is the highest number you want to stop at so if you put in stop=5
the sequence would stop at [5,5,5,5...]
This stepper shows the first number that equals the last.
This generates combinations with replacement. """
    numb1=1
    while numb1<stop:
        #print(numb1)
        l[0]=numb1
        NeL=0 
        while l[len(l)-1]<=numb1: 
            if l[NeL]==l[len(l)-1]:
                l[NeL]+=1
                l[(NeL+1):]=[1]*((len(l))-(NeL+1))
                print(l)
                """iter_2s=NeL+1
                while iter_2s<=(len(l)-1): #this is different from above
                    l[iter_2s]=2
                    iter_2s+=1
                    print(l)"""
                NeL=-1
            NeL+=1
        numb1+=1
```